# What is the setfile equivalent on Lion (OS X 10.7)?

Tags: osx-lion

How can I achieve the equivalent of `setfile -type 'sbDB' ~/myfile` on OS X 10.7, which no longer seems to support the `setfile` command?

I happen to know that the equivalent of `setfile -a V ~/myfile` is now `chflags hidden ~/myfile`. But how do I do I set a custom type like for instance `sbDB` - when I try `chflags sbDB ~/myfile` it says "invalid flag".

Comment: What is the expected outcome of the 'setfile' command? When I run it on an empty file with no extension (created via `touch`) there is no output, but Finder shows the file as a 'Sidebar DropBox folder icon" which makes me think that setfile is working on Lion (10.7.1) for me.

Comment: @TJ, it doesn't for me - i simply get `-bash: setfile: command not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Xcode.

I am (99.999%) sure that SetFile is part of that (I wish it wasn't).

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12

Comment: I'll accept this answer, but I believe there should be a way around this, without having to install Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

You can just download the latest CLI tools for `XCode` [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-). Select the package for your OS X version. I just downloaded the November Mountain Lion `XCode` tools, and app `setflag` is included.

Answer (score 2):

Just to freshen up the information here, having just grappled with this: As of OS X 10.8.2 SetFile is still no longer included in a regular base install (to the best of my knowledge). I have read that as of 10.4.X it could have been found under `/Library/Receipts`.
Source: [MacRumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=892196)

It also now seems that xcode no longer installs its resources into the root directory `/Developer/` but instead keeps all its resources within itself, i.e. with in the package contents (right-click → Show Package Contents). I can't give the path at the moment as I'm not on a 10.8 box, but it didn't take me long to find it once I was in there.

If there is a method that supersedes SetFile which doesn't require dependances outside of a base install, I'd sure like to know about it!